# Static files not loading for Django in Amazon EC2

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2

Static files are not loaded during deployment though it works perfectly on development

I have spent more than 2 days to solve this issue but still not being able to figure out. I would appreciate if anyone could help.

All of the static files are in a folder named static

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django.conf

```
       server  {
            listen 80;
            server_name my_server_name;

       location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/booking_django/app.sock;
                    }

        location /static/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias /home/ubuntu/booking_django/bookmed/static/;

                    }

        }
```

settings.py

```
     STATIC_URL = '/static/'
     STATIC_ROOT= '/home/ubuntu/booking_django/bookmed/static '
     STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),]
```